# Logic Apps - authentication loop in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, connector, azure-logic-apps

When adding the "Dynamics365 for operations" connector inside my Logic App flow and try to connect with it i get the following error:

A new window pops up asking for my credentials. Upon entering my credentials the page becomes white with on the top "working..." After a while i get the error Timeout.

I tried the following solutions:

- Starting Visual Studio in admin: had partial success, now i get one setup further into the authentication but i still get into the same authentication loop.
- Opening the link in Google Chrome just says

  > {"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"consentInfo":["No consent server information was associated with this request."]}}
- I have added the link to trusted sites on IE.
- Disabled security in the internet options of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of trial and error i managed to fix it!
For some reason i had to disable the **"Anonymous Authentication"** in the IIS manager in my default web site and enable the **"Forms Authentication"**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having issue with just Dynamics 365 for Operations connector or is this a common issue (for example with Office 365/SharePoint/etc)? Also, are you also seeing the issue in portal.azure.com?

Additionally, we have enabled logging feature in our most recent update (ver 1.1.0):
a. Open developer command prompt for VS2015
b. Run following command to start VS with activity logging enabled. devenv.exe /log c. Repro the issue in this instance and close it. d. You can find the activity log at location : %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml e. Please send us this file to us.
If you can share the logs with logicappsbug@microsoft.com, we can further assist you on this specific problem.

Thanks,
Max